# HTML form submit location

Tags: html

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/search/">
    <input type="text" name="query"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

I want to be able to, on click of the button, to make the request go to: `/search/[query-text]` instead of `/search/?query=[query-text]`

Is this possible to do WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT and without doing additional redirects?

Comment: by default its a GET request. but it doesn't do what i want it do. re-read my post

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to achieve that ?

Comment: You didn't have that additional text in your question originally. No there isn't without Javascript or a server-side redirect.

Comment: Just wondering, what are the constraints leading you to the question? Is this for lack of server-side scripting, `noscript` or screen readers? There may be a solution or something if there's a specific set of environmental constraints you're working with.

Comment: i just don't want to do an additional redirect.. was wondering if i could simply send the request like that directly. but it looks like i'll have to stick with the redirect. if there is anything i can do to speed up or minimize resource usage, i want to do that

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a way of being able to this.  The behaviour of the GET method is to append all the form fields in the pattern ?name1=value1&name2=value2 . That will happen at the browser level.

If you are trying to use this form so that you can type in the last part of a URL - why not use the POST method and then do a server-side redirect?